# Could not load the driver java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, dbconnection

I have a problem with connecting my java and mysql database was working fine yesterday but now is not working here is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    try 
    {
        Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println ("Could not load the driver");
    }

    String user, pass, host, database;
    user = "Michael";
    pass = "Blaine22";
    host = "localhost";
    database = "maintenance_work";

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
            ("jdbc:mysql://"+host+":3306/"+database, user, pass);

    conn.setAutoCommit(false);


    //Menu code:
    appSchoolMaintenance newWork = new appSchoolMaintenance();
    newWork.statement1(); // opens the start method


}
```

Comment: You haven't needed the Class.forName() line for about ten years. Just remove it. You may then get another error, or the same error again, but this time at least you'll be running up to date code.

Comment: @EJP> Do you offer connection pool?

Comment: Is this exactly the project that you've run yesterday?

Comment: did u added the jar to your lib ?

Comment: @mok What on earth are you talking about? I offer many products and services, but a connection pool isn't one of them.

Comment: @EJP> Do you say you load the driver with a service? Please represent some references so as I can read about it, cause I always use Class.forName, except the android.

Comment: Added mysql connnector bin jar and it wont do anything now

Comment: it compiles okay, but cant find a driver for some reason

Comment: @mok I say what I said. 'Just remove it'. Nothing more: nothing less. You don't need it, since JDBC 4. Period. You don't need to put words into my mouth.

Comment: @ejp> Ok, it was just a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started to work again - tried all the suggestions but started working again no rhyme or reason to it! thanks for the help though

Answer (score 3):

Add *MySQL JDBC driver* (you can get it here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) to application's *classpath* and remove unnecessary piece of code:

```
    try 
    {
        Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println ("Could not load the driver");
    }
```

Comment: that download doesnt really do anything though, thanks though

Comment: this downloads as an msi - dont know how to add to classpath?

Comment: You don't need MSI. Select 'Platform Independent', download archive. Inside archive you will found something like 'mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar'. Unpack this JAR file and add it to your application's classpath using IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to connect directly with MySQL JDBC driver

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver driver = new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();
Connection conn = driver.
            connect("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?user=root&password=root", null);
```

if this code does compile you are missing MySQL JDBC driver on the classpath

Comment: It states package com.mysql.jdbc does not exist on the  com.mysql.jdbc.Driver driver = new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver(); bit?

Comment: Then the jar with the driver is not on your Classpath.